# Program crashed when triggering Http Function to query entity state?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I am a starter in Azure Functions and durable Entities. I want to do the following things:

1. Create a durable entity and it has a state called systemList;
2. Create a queue trigger function to consume messages in my queue and store them in the entity state I just created.
3. create a http trigger function to get the current state of the entity;

And I met some problems in the 3rd step.

The code is as follows:

```
//HttpTriggerFunction.cs:
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace **.Function
{
    public static class HttpTriggerQueryEntity
    {
        [FunctionName("QueryEntity")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function)] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableEntityClient client)
        {
            var entityId = new EntityId(nameof(ProcessingListEntity), "processing_message_total");
            EntityStateResponse<JObject> stateResponse = await client.ReadEntityStateAsync<JObject>(entityId);
           
            //await client.SignalEntityAsync(entityId, "Empty");

            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,stateResponse.EntityState);
        }
    }
}
```

```
//blockData.cs
#nullable enable
using System;

namespace **.Function
{
    public class BlockData
    {
        public string? id { get; set; }
        public string? SessionId { get; set; }
        public string? MachineId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime? End { get; set; }
        public string? Activity {get; set;}
        public string? BlobId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
//Entity.cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace **.Function
{
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class ProcessingListEntity
    {
        public ProcessingListEntity(){
            systemList = new Dictionary<string, BlockData>();
        }

        [JsonProperty("systemList")]
        public Dictionary<string, BlockData> systemList {get; set;}

        public void Add(BlockData blockData) {

            if (!this.systemList.ContainsKey(blockData.MachineId)) {
                this.systemList.Add(blockData.MachineId, blockData);
                return;
            }
            else {
                this.systemList[blockData.MachineId].Start = blockData.Start;
                this.systemList[blockData.MachineId].End = blockData.End;
            }
            
        }

        public void Empty() => this.systemList = new Dictionary<string, BlockData>();

        public Dictionary<string, BlockData> Get() => this.systemList;

        [FunctionName(nameof(ProcessingListEntity))]
        public static Task Run([EntityTrigger] IDurableEntityContext ctx)
            => ctx.DispatchAsync<ProcessingListEntity>();
    }
}
```

But when I run it in my local environment and send Http query to it, the program stop. But when I changed the following line in HttpTriggerFunction.cs:

```
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,stateResponse.EntityState);
```

to

```
 return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,stateResponse.EntityState + "");
```

It can run and return the required string. But what I want to return is Json string.

So what can I do to fix my code? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do is serialize the object and encode it and then send it.

So instead of `createResponse`  return a `HttpResponseMessage`.

First you need to add packages such as:

```
using system.text;

using NewtonSoft.Json;
```

Then you can return :

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK){Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeOject(stateResponse.EntityState , Formating.Indented),Encoding.UTF8,"Response.json")}:
```

Refer the following [article](https://theflyingmaverick.com/2018/01/24/how-to-return-json-from-an-azure-function/#:%7E:text=Let%E2%80%99s%20quickly%20create%20an%20Azure%20Function%20in%20the,provide%20it%20a%20name%20and%20authentication%20model:%203.) by Callon Campbell

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0).